# Converting numpy array to cv:Mat in Opencv 3

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0

All the available solution I found dates back to 3 years which  uses modules like `cv` and functions like `cv.fromarray` which are not available in the latest version (?).

What is the current way of converting a numpy array to cv::Mat.

By the way, I am just trying to have a simple interface for data transfer between Opencv-python and Opencv-C++. I can't use the Filestorage approach in Python. What is a good way of doing this? Manually converting to cv::Mat seems like a possible solution, but doing all these internal conversion manually in my opinion is ugly.

Comment: [not easy to do](https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter) I've tried doing conversions between images in opecv python and numpy arrays (open np arrays as images without saving them as images and then opening them as cv2 images) before and then decided to just save and reopen in opencv as image. I don't know why it's so hard since there are so many ways on net that describe how to do it, but none worked for me. Looking forward to potential answers.

Comment: Maybe looking into how the [python picamera arrayOutput class](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.9/array.html) works might help.